# How to get content of the tag using JSOUP

Tags: android, css-selectors, jsoup

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="newPrice">
    <ins content="1857.00">1.857,00 <span content="TRY">TL</span></ins><span class="kdv">KDV <br>DAHİL</span>
</div>
```

I want to get 1857.00 (not 1.857,00). How can I get that?

I tried

```
Elements den = doc.select(":containsOwn("1.857,00")");
```

and it returns

```
<ins content="1857.00">1.857,00 <span content="TRY">TL</span></ins>
```

I couldn't go any further

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. If I say:

```
String price = den.attr("content");
```

it returns `1857.00`

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach is this way:

```
Element ele = doc.select("div.newPrice ins").first();
String price = ele.attr("content");
System.out.println(price);
```

If we use **.text()** it will written all the text present on the CSS path,

When it comes of attributes we have to use **.attr()** to get the desired values.